# Trouble Parsing JSON Data with php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse json data but im very bad when it comes to json and object oriented programing.

I need to retrieve the availableBalance ONLY from the account with the ID 7bf48dba-ef2a-11ed-b8b4-efdca6c6aba7.

Here is the JSON data in question. I have modified some of the answers to protect sensitive info.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [accounts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => a706b828-ef59-11ed-772f-8f17da6fccde
                    [accountNumber] => 202343140711
                    [routingNumber] => 091311229
                    [name] => Mercury Checking ••9711
                    [status] => active
                    [type] => mercury
                    [createdAt] => 2023-05-10T11:56:09.165414Z
                    [availableBalance] => 0
                    [currentBalance] => 0
                    [kind] => checking
                    [canReceiveTransactions] => 
                    [nickname] => Martinsville - Noah Parker
                    [legalBusinessName] => Batali Food LLC
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 7bf48dba-ef2a-11ed-b8b4-efdca6c6aba7
                    [accountNumber] => 202347437528
                    [routingNumber] => 091311229
                    [name] => Mercury Checking ••7428
                    [status] => active
                    [type] => mercury
                    [createdAt] => 2023-05-10T12:00:46.030313Z
                    [availableBalance] => 0
                    [currentBalance] => 0
                    [kind] => checking
                    [canReceiveTransactions] => 
                    [nickname] => Elkhart - Crystal Sandlin
                    [legalBusinessName] => Batali Food LLC
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9df02094-f1c2-119d-a6e8-c549f8cdb727
                    [accountNumber] => 202393150359
                    [routingNumber] => 091311229
                    [name] => Mercury Checking ••0389
                    [status] => active
                    [type] => mercury
                    [createdAt] => 2023-05-13T19:16:09.399458Z
                    [availableBalance] => 0
                    [currentBalance] => 0
                    [kind] => checking
                    [canReceiveTransactions] => 
                    [nickname] => Incoming - DoorDash ACH
                    [legalBusinessName] => Batali Food LLC
                )

        )

)
```

and here is my PHP code

```
<?php
//CONFIGURATION INFO
$apikey = "secret-token:mercury_production_wma_vJjkv3bHNGnv456789GkLtz8qAWaTkhRhvXFoVHRfz_yrucrem";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.mercury.com/api/v1/accounts",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Authorization: Bearer $apikey",
    "accept: application/json"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo "<textarea>";
print_r($response);
}

$getdata = json_decode($response);
?>
```

I tried several different things but I am very bad at json.

Comment: What things did you try? In what way didn't they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the json data.  That is a var_dump of the php version of the json data.  json_decode, has an extra parameter, you can set to true to transform the json structure into an array, rather than a combination of arrays and php objects.  You might want to try that.

In php you can access a public property of an object using `$obj->propertyname`

json_decode will turn json objects in php stdObjects, using php arrays of those objects when necessary.  You can tell the arrays, because they are numerically keyed  ... 0, 1 etc.

So in this case you have an object, which has an accounts property, that stores an array of account objects.  You want to iterate through that array, and check for the account object property(ies) you are interested in.

A more sophisticated way to do this would be to utilize array_filter() on the accounts array, but here I just show the use of a foreach() loop.

I also question the use of the object id property, you show as being returned.  Is that really a value you can depend upon?  I'm thinking the accountnumber is probably a better way to find the account you are looking for, as the guid value looks like something that might change with each request.

If we assume, that id is indeed always the same, then something like this will probably work:

```
$getdata = json_decode($response);
foreach ($getdata->accounts as $obj) {
    if ($obj->id == '7bf48dba-ef2a-11ed-b8b4-efdca6c6aba7') {
        echo "Account balance: {$obj->availableBalance}";
    }
}
```

Change to check for equivalence to `$obj->accountNumber` if you notice the id changes.